# Can we also use “off”?

Tags: grammar

How much money did we make from the store?

Can we also write:

How much money did we make off the store?

Comment: What makes you think you can use *make off* in your example sentence? What research have you done so far? Please, add some information to your question as to what you are asking exactly, and at what point you think it is wrong/correct to use *"make off"*. It would help people to provide a detailed answer.

Comment: Informal way of saying.

Comment: Normally one would not say "make off the store" (sounds like you're stealing it) but rather "make off of the store".  Though when spoken the "of" would likely be swallowed -- "make offa the store".

Answer (score 0):

Sure, either of your "instances" would **not** be **un**acceptable in everyday, vernacular speaking, orally or as written dialog; but not so for Standard English writing. Your Certified Public Accountant would likely be more apt to say that your store operation had garnered some amount of gross revenue or of profit, the latter of which you were free to dispose of by your own volition. ...your cash "take" in, from, out of, by, or off the enterprise, so to speak.

Comment: Hello, Steven. This answer may be **not** **un**acceptable on many websites dealing with English usage, but, as you will see if you check, ELU almost always requires answers that have supporting evidence. Note that, as @haha implies, reasonable research is needed to accompany questions here also.

Comment: Thank you, Edwin. I must confess to not ever have become inculcated to studying the literature (called research by increasing numbers) in support of statements regarding subject of which I have authoritative knowledge. That said, I can understand the need for panaceas in such an environment as Online Q&A, and will make effort at reform, or "keeping out" as appropriate.

Comment: ' I must confess to not ever have become inculcated to studying ...' doesn't strike me as being the writing of one with authoritative knowledge of the language.

Comment: Thank you. I give up...but not the hope that one day it will. What struck you is a typo, not a basis of judgment for the judiciously minded.  Truce..I suggest.

Comment: Just 9 hits found in a Google search for 'became inculcated to' suggests a rather bigger problem than the typo. // There is probably just one contributor to the site who is not expected to always provide references (though he usually does), and he {[John Lawler](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/)} is Professor Emeritus of Linguistics at the University of Michigan, much published and already peer-reviewed.  As @tchrist has ...

Comment: said, 'We are looking for more substantial answers with documented references, not merely [statements that may possibly be no more than] personal opinion. Those are just comments, not answers. ' // 'Truce' seeks to subvert the thrust of what is being said here, implying that something personal is involved. ELU is self-policing; the rules have been around for a long time.  I suggest you look at the Help Center to check on actual ELU policy.